Override the libraries settings for all tasks of a specific target in databricks asset bundles
How can I override the task settings for all tasks in a specific target without having to name each task by its task_key individually?
I know I can do the following to override the libraries setting for specific tasks in my dev target. But I need to (repetitively) list every single task in my job, which can get quite long.
Is there a way to override the libraries setting for ALL tasks in my target? The wildcard operator for task_key does not work / does not seem to be implemented.
targets:
  dev:
    mode: development
    workspace:
      host: https://xxx-xxxxxx.x.azuredatabricks.net
    resources:
      jobs:
        my_job_name:
          tasks:
            - task_key: ingestion
              libraries:
                - whl: ./dist/*.whl
                - pypi:
                    package: some-package==${var.some_package_version}
                    repo: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/stihl/xxxx/_packaging/xxx/pypi/simple/
            - task_key: preparation
              libraries:
                - whl: ./dist/*.whl
                - pypi:
                    package: some-package==${var.some_package_version}
                    repo: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/stihl/xxxx/_packaging/xxx/pypi/simple/


I was able to achieve this with yaml anchoring. It feels a bit jenky, but seems to work and cuts down on that boilerplate.
I will leave only the important parts of the yaml in the answer here. The important part is the libs property, and how its referenced under the task_key.
---
# deployment.yml
---
resources:
  jobs:
    example-dab-workflow:
      libs: &libs
        libraries:
          - pypi:
              package: llama-index==0.10.43
          - pypi:
              package: pytest==8.3.2
          - pypi:
              package: transformers==4.41.1
          - whl: ../dist/*.whl

      name:  "example-dab"

      tasks:
        - task_key: example_task
          existing_cluster_id: abc1234-foo999-barre
          python_wheel_task:
            package_name: example_dab
            entry_point: "example_entrypoint"
          <<: *libs


Ah, great idea! I didn't even use YAML anchors up until today :D It does reduce the number of lines 7-fold for me, which is good enough for now. It would be fantastic if Databricks actually supported overwriting task parameters with a wild-card for the task-key (so I can overwrite each environment separately with one line), but until then, I think this is fine :)
